Running MS Excel in Kiosk mode account
We use a excel file as a dashboard for our assembly line.  We would like it to run on a PC in kiosk mode.  However, when I setup the account, no office apps are available for selection in the app selection.  Can this be done another way?

Did you install them?  Office is not included with Windows.

Yes, its available on the laptop.  But, its local download 2016.

I don't know what you mean by "available on the laptop" if Excel is not available for selection.
